# SourcetreeでGitHubにPushするとエラーとなる

Tags: git, sourcetree

SourcetreeでGitHubにPushすると以下のエラーがでます。
どのようにすべきが、教えてください。

```
git -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v https://github.com/iOS-Pro/GitTest.git refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main 
One or more of this task's arguments is invalid. They cannot start with '-', and must follow git ref-format rules: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html
Completed with errors, see above
```

なお、Xcodeは、print文を3行追加しただけです。
よろしくお願いします。